# Phonegap Barcode scanner settings

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, pdf417

I am making application for android which includes barcode scanner. I am using Barcodescanner plugin but i have really big problem with settings. It can read simple barcodes even QR barcode but it won't read PDF417 barcode.

I installed plugin like this:
cordova plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git

I have two questions:

1. How to increase viewfinder (crop) area? My area is much smaller than original Barcode scanner application which i have installed from google play.
2. There is no settings (at least i could not find them) where i can enable PDF 417 reader. In original application that reader is disabled and you have to enable it by checking it. Maybe for android plugin that reader is enabled by default but if so why i cannot read even very simple pdf417 barcode.

P.S. I am not using Phonegap Build.
Please answer me asap.

Comment: You should put Android in your title since all the answers are coming back with java and you have the tag of android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm maintaining a fork which does support PDF417 on Android: https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/BarcodeScanner

Answer (score 2):

Viewfinder (crop) area can be increased by changing the "MAX_FRAME_WIDTH" and "MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT" in "CameraManager.java" (lines 44 and 45). CameraManager.java can be found in:

yourproject/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/src/android/LibraryProject/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraManager.java

After that you have to re-build the library project:

> So assuming you have the Android SDK and tools (ie: ant) then what you need to do is go to the directory:
>
> yourpoject\plugins\com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner\src\android\LibraryProject
>
> you'll need to put a local.properties file in this folder, or make one, it only needs one line:
>   sdk.dir=path/to/your/android/sdk
>
> then assuming you have all the correct build tools and api packages (i did not, had to open my sdk manager and install build tools 19.1 and api 17) you would just need to run:
>   ant release
>
> which will build the executable jar, which for me showed up as:
>   yourpoject\plugins\com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner\src\android\LibraryProject\bin\classes.jar
>
> so rename it to: com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar
>   and put it under: yourpoject\plugins\com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner\src\android\
>
> also, to avoid removing/re-adding the platform (to redeploy the plugin) i also copied the file to:
>   yourproject\platforms\android\libs\com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar
>
> then just built the project.

More info about the issue can be found: https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/issues/130

Comment: Can MAX_FRAME_WIDTH and MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT be set as env vars? I'm working with an API layer (Tabris.js) which means I don't have access to Java directly (or iOS's Objective C for that matter)